# persist permissions to all files in directory HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to do a chmod 755 on all the directories and files in an HDFS directory but it wont persist all the way down.

for example, if I have a directory like this:

```
/home/set1/data1/file1.txt
```

I need to do this so my app can access it:

```
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data1/*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data1/file*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data2/*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data2/file*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data3/*
haddop fs -chmod 755 /home/set1/data3/file*
```

how do I get the permission to set for each directory and file in the path in HDFS?

Answer (score 10):

Use "-R" (Recursive) option.

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 755 /home/set1/data1/
```